# how to get a value from a json text Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get("https://api.investing.com/api/search/?t=Equities&q=amd") # i get json text from this api
data = json.loads(r.text)
if data['articles'][0]['exchange'] == 'Sydney': # the error is here      KeyError: 'exchange'
   print('success')
else:
   print('fail')
```

if i want to get the url '/equities/segue-resources-ltd' by checking if the 'exchange' is 'Sydney' which is stored in this part of the json text,  {"id":948190,"url":"/equities/segue-resources-ltd","description":"Segue Resources Ltd","symbol":"AMD","exchange":"Sydney","flag":"AU","type":"Equities"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding this correctly, the `exchange` identifier only appears in part of the json response. So, in order to get your result using the same `data` variable in your question, we can do this:

`result = [val["url"] for val in data["quotes"] if val["exchange"] == "Sydney"]`

We are using a list comprehension here, where the loop is only going through `data["quotes"]` instead of the whole json response, and for each item in that json subset, we're returning the value for `key == "url"` where the `exchange == "Sydney"`. Running the line above should get you:

`['/equities/segue-resources-ltd']`

As expected. If you aren't comfortable with list comprehensions, the more conventional loop-version of it looks like:

```
result = []
for val in data["quotes"]:
    if val["exchange"] == "Sydney":
        result.append(val["url"])

print(result)
```

Comment: This is perfect but im not quite sure on how does it work, can you explain a little bit about what does val do?

Comment: val is just a random string identified in a loop. It is similar to saying: **for val in data:** You can change val to any other string like "k" if you wanted

Comment: @PythonNoobie I've updated my answer to include the more traditional (less pythonic) looking for loop. Let me know if you still are unsure! :) List comprehensions are the place to start

Comment: oh i see what u did now, now it looks much more familiar to me :D, Thanks a lot appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError: 'exchange'` means that the dictionary `data['articles'][0]` did not have a key `'exchange'`.

Depending on your use case, you may want to iterate over the whole list of articles:

```
for article in data['articles']:
    if 'exchange' in article and article['exchange'] == 'Sydney':
        ...  # Your code here
```

If you only want to check the first article, then use `data['articles'][0].get('exchange')`.  The [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method will return `None` if the key is not present instead of throwing a `KeyError`.

Comment: for article in data['articles']:
    if 'exchange' in article and article['exchange'] == 'Sydney':
        print('yeah')
    else:
        print('noo')
i tried this but it still just jump straight to the else loop. how come

Comment: @PythonNoobie That would indicate that none of the items in the list `data['articles']` has the entry `"exchange": "Sydney"`.  It looks like you should probably be iterating over `data['quotes']` instead.